# Alamofire doesn't recognize result as JSON

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire, guzzle

I am calling a public API from PHP using Guzzle. It returns valid JSON (validated on JSONLint.com). However, when I try to return that to my iOS app, Alamofire doesn't like it. I tried decoding the JSON and then re-encoding it, but I get the same result. I can't figure out why Alamofire won't accept it. I have tested the web service with Paw, and it returns a JSON result with a `content-type` of `application/json`.

The error I get is:

> JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn’t be
>   read because it isn’t in the correct format.

PHP code:

```
$url = "myUrl";
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->get($url, [
'headers' =>  [
    'Authorization' => "Bearer myKey",
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]
]);

header('Content-type: application/json');
$results = $res->getBody();
$this->response($results, 200);
```

Swift code:

```
let url = serviceUrl + "currentwar"     
let params = [
    "clanId" : "\(clanId)",
]

Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            self.json = JSON(data)
            print(self.json as Any)

            // process data

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                // populate view
            })

        case .failure(let error):
            print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Try using `responseString` instead of `responseJSON` and convert the string to a JSON and parse.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh, I tried this, but can't seem to do anything with the resulting string. Converting it to JSON just returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the API from a REST client such as [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to validate the results. Because the browser can render the HTML content, you may not be able to see it in the browser window, but you can easily check that out from the page source view. 
I always check the APIs in Postman because it ensures no errors are there in the API from server side and that the API consumer can easily use that API.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I use Paw as my REST client (native app that is much nicer than Postman). As well, I mentioned that I validated the JSON at JSONLint.com. That said, I did run it through Postman as well, and got valid JSON back.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by wrapping the JSON in square brackets.

```
$result = "[" . $result . "]";
```